# Java JNI and Vala - Undefined Symbol: g_once_init_enter

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, glib, vala

I wrote a tiny Vala class, compiled that to C code, generated JNI header and implementation to call the Vala / CCode from.

So at the end I have two headers and two implementation files which I compile with gcc to a JNI library. it compiles fine and results in a library.

When I run the Java app, including this library, I get `symbol lookup error` in the lib.

The interesting part is: `undefined symbol: g_once_init_enter` - it is not in my code, but in the glib code, generated by `valac`.

So, JNI C code calls Vala C code which calls glib stuff. Java seems to not find the glib part.

Anyone any idea, what to do here?

Comment: are you static linking the glib library into your shared library?  If not, you will need to load the glib library as well

Comment: @Samhain: Yes, I thought so too... so I did:
`
  static { System.loadLibrary("glib-2.0"); }
  static { System.loadLibrary("test"); }
`
and still get:
`
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtest.so: undefined symbol: g_once_init_enter
`
Both libs are in that specified directory, so it should not be undefined...

Comment: It's dynamic linking.

Comment: It works now.
https://github.com/DasJott/mkjni

Comment: @DasJott You should add an answer with your solution in order to help future visitors of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this was a problem with Das Jott’s code to generate compiler command lines to generate C files, and it was fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/DasJott/mkjni/commit/1318a138171c1bb7be6afbcc2253f09f1e05c5a5). It looks like they were trying to execute bash-style shell script using `exec()`, which resulted in the `pkg-config` flags for `glib-2.0` never making it into the linker command line.

tl;dr: As Samhain said, the root problem was failing to link against `glib-2.0`.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't into that topic anymore :(